# Windows Phone 7 Office Hub

Tags: windows-phone-7, office

В wp7 есть возможность встроить приложение в хаб галереи, называется это [Photos_Extra_Share](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?win=35&clid=124993&text=Photos_Extra_Share&lr=15)

Есть ли что-то подобное под Office, ведь там есть пункт меню "Отправить", и помниться, что в какой-то книжке по теме намекалось на подобную возможность, но конкретный материал так и не удалось найти.

Answer (score 2):

Такой возможности для Office Hub нет, ни в WP7, ни в WP8.

Comment: Только Interop.

Comment: А интеропа у сторонних разработчиков тоже нет.

Comment: Ну, я к тому, что всё-же, можно, но только через Interop, но тогда приложение нельзя будет опубликовать в Marketplace.